# Four quadrant chart

Tags: c#, charts, devexpress, infragistics, finance

I have requirement to plot Fundamental Score and Technical Score for each ticker across four quadrant. So that graph will be divided exactly in four quadrant and multiple tickers will be graphed based on its Fundamental and Technical Score. In the middle there will be X axis (ranging from -100 to +100)and Y axis (ranging from -100 to +100)

How can I do this using either DevExpress or Infragistics controls ?

Thanks

Comment: What is the problem you are having? In general you're likely to get more response if you show that you've attempted something.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use DXChart's ScatterLine chart to accomplish this, as outlined [here](http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/p/Q394957.aspx) on DevExpress's support site (4th post).

Comment: I end up using Constant Line at 50 for X and Y, Thanks